# Input/Target size mismatch when training a downstream BERT for classification (huggingface pretrained)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface

I am training a BERT model with a downstream task to classify movie genres. I am using HuggingFace pretrained model (aleph-bert since data is in Hebrew)

When training, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (3744) to match target batch_size (16).
```

This is my notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mqIUPnLOu_H-URn5tzE6gGySsW3oAcRY?usp=sharing

The error happens in the `compute_loss functions`, while performing the cross_entropy step.

My batch size is 16 but for some reason the bert output returns a different size.

The relevant code:

```
def data_prep_for_genre(genre):
    X = movies_df['overview']
    y = movies_df[genre].rename('labels', inplace=True).astype(float)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
    X_train = tokenizer(X_train.to_list(), truncation=True)
    X_test = tokenizer(X_test.to_list(), truncation=True)

    train_dataset = TextData(X_train, y_train.to_list())
    test_dataset = TextData(X_test, y_test.to_list())

    # define model:
    model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("onlplab/alephbert-base", num_labels=2)

    return model, train_dataset, test_dataset


class MyTrainer(Trainer):  
   def compute_metrics(pred):
      labels = pred.label_ids
      preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
      precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(labels, preds, average='binary')
      acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
      return {
          'accuracy': acc,
          'f1': f1,
          'precision': precision,
          'recall': recall
      }

    training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          
    num_train_epochs=10,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,   
    warmup_steps=50,                 
    weight_decay=0.01,               
    logging_dir='./logs',            
    logging_steps=10
)

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

for genre in GENRE_SET:
  model, train_dataset, test_dataset = data_prep_for_genre(genre)
  trainer = MyTrainer(
    model=model,                        
    args=training_args,                 
    train_dataset=train_dataset,        
    # eval_dataset=test_dataset,        
    data_collator=data_collator
  )
  trainer.train()
```